# Expanding \thechapter immediately

Tags: expansion

This is a spinoff of another question I posted here.

```
\documentclass[8pt]{book}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand{\mychapter}[1]{\chapter{#1} \hypertarget{chapter::\theHchapter}{}}
\newcommand{\refChapter}{\hyperlink{chapter::\theHchapter}{\thechapter}}

\newcommand{\addTimeline}[2]{%
  \ifcsname timeLine#1\endcsname
    \csappto{timeLine#1}{\unexpanded{\\& #2 & } \thechapter}%
  \else
    \csdef{timeLine#1}{\unexpanded{\\\textbf{#1} & #2 & } \thechapter}%
  \fi
}

\newcount\timelineCounter
\newcommand{\printTimeline}[2]{%
  \def\timelineData{}%
  \timelineCounter=#1\relax
  \loop \ifnum \timelineCounter<#2
    \edef\timelineData{\expandonce{\timelineData}\csuse{timeLine\the\timelineCounter}}%
    \advance \timelineCounter 1
  \repeat
\begin{tabular}{c p{7cm} c}
  \timelineData
\end{tabular}
}


\begin{document}

\mychapter{First}
 \addTimeline{4}{Event1}
 \addTimeline{19}{Event2}
 \addTimeline{2}{Event3}

\mychapter{Second} 
 \addTimeline{29}{Event4}
 \addTimeline{15}{Event5}
 \addTimeline{19}{Event6}

\mychapter{Timeline}
  \printTimeline{1}{30}


\end{document}
```

I expected it to print two empty chapters followed by a Chapter 3, called Timeline with

```
  2 Event3        1
  4 Event1        1
 15 Event5        2
 19 Event2        1
    Event6        2
 29 Event4        2
```

but instead in the third column I get all "3". In the ideal scenario I'd use `\refChapter` command that I created, instead of the `\thechapter`, but the former doesn't compile. I am a bit clueless as how to expand this kind of expression. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: It looks like you've got two separate accounts, which means you cannot edit your original post or leave comments. The Stack Exchange staff can [merge them together for you](//tex.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge).

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `\cseappto` and `\csedef`, but this requires another `\unexpanded` around the part you don't want to expand:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand{\mychapter}[1]{\chapter{#1} \hypertarget{chapter::\theHchapter}{}}
\newcommand{\refChapter}{\hyperlink{chapter::\theHchapter}{\thechapter}}

\newcommand{\addTimeline}[2]{%
  \ifcsname timeLine#1\endcsname
    \cseappto{timeLine#1}{\unexpanded{\unexpanded{\\& #2 & }} \thechapter}%
  \else
    \csedef{timeLine#1}{\unexpanded{\unexpanded{\\\textbf{#1} & #2 & }} \thechapter}%
  \fi
}

\newcount\timelineCounter
\newcommand{\printTimeline}[2]{%
  \def\timelineData{}%
  \timelineCounter=#1\relax
  \loop \ifnum \timelineCounter<#2
    \edef\timelineData{\expandonce{\timelineData}\csuse{timeLine\the\timelineCounter}}%
    \advance \timelineCounter 1
  \repeat
\begin{tabular}{c p{7cm} c}
  \timelineData
\end{tabular}
}


\begin{document}

\mychapter{First}
 \addTimeline{4}{Event1}
 \addTimeline{19}{Event2}
 \addTimeline{2}{Event3}

\mychapter{Second} 
 \addTimeline{29}{Event4}
 \addTimeline{15}{Event5}
 \addTimeline{19}{Event6}

\mychapter{Timeline}
  \printTimeline{1}{30}


\end{document}
```

[image]

The same with `expl3`, but with less problems with expansion, because we can expand `\theHchapter` and `\thechapter` when the main macro is being called.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set_eq:NN \latexchapter \chapter

% modify \chapter to add a hypertarget
\RenewDocumentCommand{\chapter}{sO{#3}m}
 {
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
   {
    \latexchapter*{#3}
   }
   {
    \latexchapter[#2]{\hypertarget{chapter::\theHchapter}{#3}}
   }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\addTimeline}{smm}
 { % here \theHchapter and \thechapter are expanded prior to doing the hard work
  \benedict_timeline_add:xxnn { \IfBooleanF{#1}{\theHchapter} } { \thechapter } { #2 } { #3 }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \benedict_timeline_add:nnnn
 {
  \tl_if_exist:cTF { l_benedict_timeline_#3_tl }
   { % the header has already appeared
    \tl_put_right:cn { l_benedict_timeline_#3_tl } { & #4 }
   }
   { % the header is new
    \tl_new:c { l_benedict_timeline_#3_tl }
    \tl_put_right:cn { l_benedict_timeline_#3_tl } { \textbf{#3} & #4 }
   }
  % now add the reference; #3 is the header
  % #1 and #2 are \theHchapter and \thechapter (expanded)
  \benedict_timeline_add_ref:nnn { #3 } { #1 } { #2 }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \benedict_timeline_add:nnnn { xx }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \benedict_timeline_add_ref:nnn
 {
  \tl_if_empty:nTF { #2 } % \theHchapter
   {% modify here for the formatting
    \tl_put_right:cn { l_benedict_timeline_#1_tl } { & \S #3 \\ }
   }
   {
    \tl_put_right:cn { l_benedict_timeline_#1_tl } { & \S \hyperlink{chapter::#2}{#3} \\ }
   }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\printTimeline}{mm}
 {
  \tl_clear:N \l__benedict_timeline_body_tl
  \int_step_inline:nnnn { #1 } { 1 } { #2 }
   {
    \tl_if_exist:cT { l_benedict_timeline_##1_tl }
     {
      \tl_put_right:Nv \l__benedict_timeline_body_tl { l_benedict_timeline_##1_tl }
     }
   }
  \begin{tabular}{c p{7cm} c}
  \tl_use:N \l__benedict_timeline_body_tl
  \end{tabular}
 }

\tl_new:N \l__benedict_timeline_body_tl
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_put_right:Nn { Nv }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\chapter{First}

\addTimeline{4}{Event1}
\addTimeline{19}{Event2}
\addTimeline{2}{Event3}

\chapter{Second} 

\addTimeline{29}{Event4}
\addTimeline{15}{Event5}
\addTimeline{19}{Event6}

\chapter{Timeline}

\printTimeline{1}{30}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'd never guess you have to nest those unexpanded. This works perfectly for the \thechapter case, but it fails to compile for \refChapter. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: @Benedict `\refChapter` is not fully expandable

Comment: My main problem with latex right now is that it feels pretty much a trail-and-error effort, as I have never heard of a latex debugger. I've just found out that \S\thechapter cannot go in there either for whatever reason, and \thepart.\thechapter works for this small sample, but not at all in my real document. The error messages are more confusing than helpful as they do not reflect the true nature of the error in most cases.

Is there any way in which a mere mortal can debug this kind of behaviour without having to annoy people in StackExchange?

Comment: @Benedict I think you are approaching the problem from the wrong point of view. Anyway, `\S` cannot go unprotected in an `\edef` so you should use `\noexpand\S`.

Comment: \noexpand\S\thechapter also doesn't work. And what do you mean with wrong point of view?

Comment: @Benedict Since it should be unexpanded twice, the same strategy applies: `\noexpand\noexpand\noexpand\S`.

Comment: @Benedict I added an improved version with `expl3` that avoids many problems with expansion.

Comment: thank you very much. Your \noexpand suggestion works. I've found out (throught trial and error) that \thepart.\thechapter didn't work because I was using \usepackage[greek,english]{babel}, and it is probably somehow modifying \thepart (but not \thechapter). Any idea how to circumvent this?

Comment: @Benedict One of the reasons `expl3` exists is for avoiding such problems. Oh! And `babel-greek` does very bad things to `\thechapter`.